# Using UrlConnection Openstream mutiple times in a loop

Tags: android

I have a application on android where I want to read data from a url on the 3g and wifi interface of my phone. I am using the following code

```
read_data() {
  url = new URL("http://0xbadc0ffee.de/plHUGE.txt");
  UrlConnection conn = url.openConnection;
  reader = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
  //Then I write this into a FileOutput stream
  reader.close();
}
```

This works fine when I run it twice on the 3g and wifi interface. But when I put this in a loop it fails to get the Inputstream. Initially I doubted if the stream was getting closed properly or not, but if it wasnt how would it work the first 2 times on the 2 interfaces? I have been stuck with this for over 2 days now... Any pointers are appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection) link will help you. Take one of his working examples and modify it. My guess is that you are probably running out of pooled sockets to the host you are using for the download, and I would try adding a conn.disconnect() call. It would be even better to start from that example from Tim Bray.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that the problem is not with the connection pool, its with enabling and disabling wifi.
The problem happens only after I disable wifi and enable it back. The wifi connection comes back up , but it cannot get the stream from my url.

I dont know if the wifi interface is taking too long to be active(but it does have connectivity in the meantime, pings work) or it is some problem with disabling and enabling it back. 
I am still stuck!